# Tensorflow operator gradients registration

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to understand how [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow) register gradients for its operators in general.

I have checked for code in both `tensorflow/core/ops`, `tensorflow/python/ops` and `tensorflow/cc/gradients`. It looks like all three components provides gradient registration for similar ops. For example,

```py
# In tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py
@ops.RegisterGradient("BatchMatMul")
def _BatchMatMul():
...
```

```
// In tensorflow/core/ops/math_grad.cc
Status BatchMatMulGrad(attrs, g){...}
REGISTER_OP_GRADIENT("BatchMatMul", BatchMatMulGrad);
```

```
// In tensorflow/cc/gradients/math_grad.cc
Status BatchMatMulGrad(...){...}
REGISTER_GRADIENT_OP("BatchMatMul", BatchMatMulGrad);
```

What is the point of have duplicate definition of gradient to same operators?